# Perforce diff for excel files

Tags: excel, diff, perforce

I have a bunch of excel file sitting on perforce. I would want to do diff for these excel files similar to how I do for other files (like java,cs etc) in perforce.

I tried to look for a plug in and found P4OFC is the one which works well only for doing diff of word file and not for excel file.

Can someone tell me how do I do diff for excel file sitting in perforce.

Comment: Sorry, could not find tool for Perforce... By default, latest TortoiseSVN has diff/merge plugin support for Word and Excel (any Office version). Other than that: `xdocdiff - diff for Word, Excel, PowerPoint, pdf files with TortoiseSVN` http://freemind.s57.xrea.com/xdocdiff/e/index.html This plugin will "convert" Office format file into text first before diff/merge with WinMerge. It doesn't look nice, though unlike TortoiseSVN. But, TortoiseSVN plugin requires Word and/or Excel application

Answer (score 2):

I think that the latest version of [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) can do spreadsheets, you might want to grab the free trial and give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

If your are under Windows with Excel installed, have a look at [SSCL](https://github.com/domalb/spresheecomplaun).

In Perforce settings you can set sscl.exe to be invoked for diff of xls/xlsx files.
SSCL should find and start spreadsheetcompare.exe which is a Office tool that will do the job.