# Perforce Diff Excel Files with SSCL

Tags: excel, diff, perforce

this is a continuation of the following stack overflow question: [Perforce diff for excel files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801136/perforce-diff-for-excel-files?rq=1)

I'd like to use the solution proposed by domalb, which is to use SSCL.  I've downloaded the SSCL solution and am able to successfully diff excel files when using the cmd prompt.  However, I'm having trouble getting the arguments to work correctly in Perforce.

In perforce, I go to Edit -> Preferences and select "Diff" from the left menu.  I then "specify diff application by extension (overrides default).  I set the extension to .xlsx, set the application to sscl.exe, and set the arguments to %1 %2 -d="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\DCF"

However, this does not work.  When I turn on verbose logging in the argument list, I see the following error message:

[image]

How can I resolve this error when passing in the SSCL arguments? It looks like it cuts off the directory at the first space, so it is not respecting the double quotes?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use Windows "short names"? That is, C:\Progra~1\Micros~1\Office16\DCF, etc. Run `dir /x` to get the actual short names for your case. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename

Comment: That worked - thanks Bryan!